# M2 Enterprise: How to add Special Price for product from date to date programmatically?

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, magento-2.1, special-price, catalog-staging

I want to add a **Special Price** for a product from date to date programmatically by code but don't know how.

I can set in admin but I want to use code to save multiple products.

I use Enterprise Edition and don't have the date fields. Instead the **content staging** feature is used to schedule price changes.

[image]

**in EE using scheduled:**
[image]

**in Scheduled:**
[image]

Comment: have you found the solution? If yes, please update

Comment: Anyone still looking for a solution? I came across this article: [https://trive.digital/magento/programatically-schedule-product-content-changes-magento-2-enterprise/](https://trive.digital/magento/programatically-schedule-product-content-changes-magento-2-enterprise/) It works out for me for the most part. Still tweaking it for special price targeting a particular store.

Comment: Any solution how can we achieve this using API?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Magento\Staging\Model\Entity\Update\Save` to schedule a new update:

```
$this->stagingUpdateSave->execute(
    [
        'entityId' => 1234,           // <-- your product id
        'stagingData' => [
            'mode' => 'save',
            'name' => 'Test Special Price Update',
            'start_time' => 'Feb 25, 2017 12:00 AM'
            'end_time' => 'Feb 26, 2017 12:00 AM'
         ],
        'entityData' => [
            'product' => [
                'price' => '1.00',
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

Comment: Question is to display special price from and to in `advance price` modal. OP provided reference of Schedule `start date` and `end date`.

Comment: Using this code gives an exception. Exception message: The "save" action type is invalid. Verify the action type and try again. Trace: <pre>#1 Magento\Staging\Model\Entity\Update\Save->execute(). Seems action type also has to be prepared somehow.

Answer (score 2):

In `vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

add comments to `special_from_date` and `special_to_date`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="attributesToEliminate" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="news_from_date" xsi:type="string">news_from_date</item>
                <item name="news_to_date" xsi:type="string">news_to_date</item>
                <item name="custom_design_from" xsi:type="string">custom_design_from</item>
                <item name="custom_design_to" xsi:type="string">custom_design_to</item>
                <!--<item name="special_from_date" xsi:type="string">special_from_date</item>
                <item name="special_to_date" xsi:type="string">special_to_date</item> -->
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

This will show `special from` and `special to` date in `advance price` modal. Now you can override above di.xml file in your own module.

Comment: It's not working in Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score -2):

Now run below code

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $_product->setName('Test Product');
        $_product->setTypeId('simple');
        $_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $_product->setSku('test-SKU');
        $_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $_product->setVisibility(4);
        $_product->setPrice(array(15));
        $_product->setImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
        $_product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
        $_product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test.jpg');
        $_product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                'manage_stock' => 1,
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, 
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, 
                'is_in_stock' => 1, 
                'qty' => 100 
            )
        );
        $_product->setCustomAttributes(array(
                'special_from_date' => "01/12/2016", 
                'special_to_date' => "11/12/2016", 
                'special_price' => 12, 
            )
        );

        $_product->save();
```

see below pic. In my case it's working fine.

[image]

Comment: thanks for advice, but i use Enterprise Edition version, it don't have field to set setSpecialFromDate or setSpecialToDate

Comment: @Init execute my updated code and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: @Init have you tried?

Comment: thanks, but i use Enterprise Edition, it don't have field Special Price From, your pic is CE version

Comment: see images updated in my question