# Magento 2 Enterprise Schedule Update Programatically

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud, schedule

M2 Enterprise uses a schedule method to update the price and special price. Would like to know how we can achieve the same functionality by coding programatically.

Found this [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148851/m2-enterprise-how-to-add-special-price-for-product-from-date-to-date-programmat) but that does not have he solution.

We need to create a console command to update the scheduled price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below code it worked for me. I used it on the Console commad as it will run in a cron job.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$versionManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager');
$productStaging = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface');
$updateRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface');
$updateFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterface');
$timezone = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone');
$storeManger = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeId = $storeManger->getStore()->getId();

$timezonefill = $timezone->getConfigTimezone(\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES, $storeId);
$currentDate = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone($timezonefill));
$date = $currentDate->format("Y-m-d");
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


/** @var \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterface $schedule */
$schedule = $updateFactory;
$schedule->setName("Price Update #");
$schedule->setStartTime("2020-06-22 00:00:00");
$schedule->setEndTime("2020-07-23 23:59:59");
$stagingRepo = $updateRepository->save($schedule);

$versionManager->setCurrentVersionId($stagingRepo->getId());
$product = $productRepository->get("123456"); // Product SKU
$product->setPrice("10"); // Price
$productStaging->schedule($product, $stagingRepo->getId());
```

Comment: Do you know in which tables scheduled data is stored?

Comment: You will find schedules in `staging_update` table. Each products has a created_in and updated_in timestamp (in catalog_product_entity) that tells Magento which product to pick.

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed a tad more validation when it comes to these fickle scheduled updates:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @param float $specialPrice
 * @param string $startTime (Y-m-d H:i:s)
 * @param string $endTime (Y-m-d H:i:s)
 * @param int $storeId
 * @return bool
 */
private function buildProductScheduledPriceUpdate(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product,
    float $specialPrice,
    string $startTime,
    string $endTime,
    string $name,
    int $storeId = 0
): bool {

    /** @var \Magento\Staging\Api\Data\UpdateInterfaceFactory */
    $stagingUpdate = $this->stagingUpdateFactory
        ->create()
        ->setName($name)
        ->setStartTime($startTime)
        ->setEndTime($endTime);

    $product
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->setSpecialPrice($specialPrice);

    try {

        /** @var \Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface */
        $stagingUpdate = $this->stagingUpdateRepository->save($stagingUpdate);
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException $e) {
        $this->logger->warning(
            __(
                "Price Schedule Validation Exception - %1",
                $e->getMessage()
            )
        );

        return false;
    }

    if ($stagingUpdate->getId()) {

        /** @var \Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager */
        $this->stagingVersionManager->setCurrentVersionId(
            $stagingUpdate->getId()
        );

        try {

            /** @var \Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface */
            return $this->stagingProductUpdate->schedule($product, $stagingUpdate->getId());
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException $e) {
            $this->logger->warning(
                __(
                    "Price Schedule Validation Exception - %1",
                    $e->getMessage()
                )
            );

            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```